# Not able to connect snowflake DB through DBeaver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

Does anyone know how to connect Snowflake DB through DBeaver?
I have installed the latest JDBC driver "snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2"
& trying to connect to Snowflake DB, but I'm getting below error:

> "JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: Connection reset.

Comment: How does your connection details dialog look in DBeaver?

Comment: Why not try the latest driver version?  And you should be able to follow the general instructions for the Snowflake JDBC driver for DBeaver. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server perhaps? You might need to configure your internet connection settings

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3.10.3 version of Snowflake JDBC jar.Its a tried and tested version on Db eaver .

Comment: Still not able to connect

Comment: HTTP connection reset means you have some connectivity issue .You may be using proxy or something to connect to Snowflake DB and there its failing .DB eaver has proxy settings too , there you can configure.

Comment: Thanks Ankur, But I have HTTP proxy where as in DB eaver. there is SOCKS proxy option only let me know hoe to configure the HTTP proxy in DB eaver

Comment: You can add the SOCKS proxy setting too in DB eaver .Select File - > New -> Db eaver -> Database Connection -> Go to new connection -> Select snowflake-> and proxy tab .

Comment: but for my company SOCKS proxy is not supported. let me know how to configure HTTP proxy.